# How to parse through <dl><dt><dd> tag using watin. I want to read data from this tags

Tags: c#, watin

I want to read the data from  tag in html using watin. is there any builtin functionality in watin to read this data. I am giving the html code below.
I want to basically read  field for the particular  field.

---

```
<\dl id="idname" class="classname">

        <dt>Date</dt>
            <dd>04/10/2012</dd>
        <dt>Lastdate</dt>
            <dd>04/10/2012</dd>
    <dt>Label 1</dt>
    <dd>
        data1</dd>

    <dt>label 2</dt>

    <dd>
        data2</dd>

    <dt>Label3</dt>

    <dd>
        data3</dd>

</dl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but you can try this:

```
var elementText =  IE.Element(Find.ById("idname")).DomContainer.Element(
                   Find.ByElement((e => e.TagName.Equals("dt" )))).Text;
```

This should return the text of first 'dt' element.